# PHP function to identify and parse unusual time format?

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm currently working with weather data feeds to assemble some accurate data. This particular feed is being pulled from Norway and has a format of 2012-01-13T19:00:00. The "T" is what throws me off.

Does anyone know if PHP will recognize this format and/or provide a function to parse this particular timestamp?

I would have thought a combo of strtotime() and date(), but apparently it only accepts English formats? I would prefer to avoid doing a regex to strip out the T but if it's necessary I'll work with it.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [PHP will recognize it](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9vWwWP), because that's a [standardized format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8601).

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2012-01-13T19:00:00');
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know it was a standard. Also nice to discover codepad, it's kinda like jsFiddle. I'll accept the answer ASAP (unless someone provides a rather detailed and awesome essay LOL)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function isValidDateTime($dateTime)
    {
        if (preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) ([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $dateTime, $matches)) {
            print_r($matches);
            if (checkdate($matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[1])) {
               return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: although deceze answered it quite well, this will be helpful for parsing any feeds that look unstandardized. thanks!